# Does Office Open XML (.docx) merging in TortoiseSVN work?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge, ms-word, docx

I'm trying to use some scripts that came from TortoiseSVN to do some [Office Open XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) (.docx) files merges, but the script doesn't seem to be working right. How does this feature normally work in TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use TortoiseSVN 1.6.6 and docx merge is working fine.
Check SVN settings -> Diff Viewer -> Advanced ...

There is a table of mime-type spicific programs. For docx I see "wscript.exe "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\Diff-Scripts\diff-docx.js" %base %mine //E:javascript".